# Phoenix LiveView socket and en external socket

Tags: phoenix-framework

I need help with something and excuse me if it seems trivial since I’m still learning phoenix.

I have a simple LiveView to view a position of an object in 3D space, the position comes form an external socket here is how I handle the incoming position

```
def handle_in("new_msg", %{"x" => posX, "y"=> posY, "z" => posZ}, socket) do
    GameLive.handle_event("new_position", %{"x" => posX, "y" => posY, "z" => posZ}, socket)
    broadcast!(socket, "new_msg", %{x: posX, y: posY, z: posZ})
    {:reply, {:ok, %{response: "Updated"}}, socket}
end
```

and here is how I handle the event

```
def handle_event("new_position", %{"x" => posX, "y" => posY, "z" => posZ}, socket) do
    {:noreply, assign(socket, %{x: posX, y: posY, z: posZ})}
end
```

I get this error whenever I try to update the position

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.481.0> terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.LiveView.assign/2
    (phoenix_live_view) lib/phoenix_live_view.ex:1252: Phoenix.LiveView.assign(%Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: GameviewWeb.RoomChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.481.0>, endpoint: GameviewWeb.Endpoint, handler: GameviewWeb.UserSocket, id: nil, join_ref: "3", joined: true, private: %{log_handle_in: :debug, log_join: :info}, pubsub_server: Gameview.PubSub, ref: "4", serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, topic: "room:lobby", transport: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.478.0>}, %{x: 5, y: 5, z: 5})
```

I now understand that I'm passing a different a type of socket to `Phoenix.LiveView.assign/2` as it expects a `Phoenix.LiveView.Socket` and I'm passing a `Phoenix.Socket`. Thanks to [Elixir Forum Community](https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-liveview-socket-and-en-external-socket/26635/2?u=aligredo).

How should I handle such a situation, I'm looking for a solution with a good practice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is to use [Pubsub](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_pubsub) that applies publisher/subscriber design pattern. Upon Pubsub notifying the subscribers, you can handle the event at each subscriber with different logic based on what you need without mixing up the sockets.